# Paypal: NVP API SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE is US and still GB shows as selected

Tags: paypal, nvp

i'm using NVP API and calling SetExpressCheckout, sending SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE with the value US or any other country code and still when payment page appears the country is Great Britain....

why is this happening?? please help me

Comment: To make it possible for someone to answer you should add some code how you call/use the API and probably which version you use (PHP, Java, .Net)

Comment: michaPau is right, give us more information about your problem, What page does it always goes to GB ? on paypal ? your website? What API call are you using

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using an old API version because
*SHIPTOCOUNTRY* is **deprecated** (since version 63). You should use *PAYMENTREQUEST_n_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE* instead.

More information here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/